# how to check which one has been clicked in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

inside of while loop, i've used

```
<asp:Button ID="<%=objReader.Item(0)%>" OnClick="btn_Click"  runat="server" CssClass="submit_button" Text="Delete" />


Sub btn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
       'You have clicked button 

    End Sub
```

to creating the button dynamically. Now, on click of particular button, it should show the information which are associated with the clicked button. Need Help !!

**Solution**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="Jobs">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnDemo" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Login_id")%>' OnCommand="btnDemo_Click" runat="server" Text="Button" /></ItemTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>

Sub btnDemo_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CommandEventArgs)
        MsgBox(e.CommandArgument)

    End Sub
```

Thanks to every one!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to implement this in a databound control, like the repeater or listview.

You could then use the CommandArgument of a button to add some arguments which are distinct for each button.

You can then handle this in the Click procedure to handle the right action at the right CommandArgument.

see: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.commandargument.aspx

Example:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptList">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDemo" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Id") %>' Text="Click me" OnCommand="btnDemo_Click"  />            
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: can you help me to set `ID` property of button from database value, like i've written in my code. I'm getting error there. thanks in advance !!